# Can't get param[:id] in control method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The method set_instrument works for the methods show, edit, update and destroy, but is not working for the method chart.
Don't know how to fix this. Here is my controller:

```
class InstrumentsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_instrument, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :chart]
      def chart
        @measurements = @instrument.measurements.order("scheduled_on asc")
      end
      def show
        @measurements = @instrument.measurements.order("scheduled_on asc")
      end
      def edit
      end
      private
        def set_instrument
          @instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])
        end
        def instrument_params
          params.require(:instrument).permit(:inst_id, :chainage, :northing, :easting,
           :latitude, :longitude, :above_tbm, :group_id, :section, :number_of_sensors,
           :review_level, :alert_level)
        end
    end
```

I am getting the error: Couldn't find Instrument without an ID in the statement `@instrument = Instrument.find(params[:id])` in method `set_instrument`.

Comment: Show your `routes.rb` file. `chart` should be a member route of `instruments` resources, maybe you mistakenly made it to be collection route?

Comment: You are not sending any arguments to the method. How do you call your `chart` method?

Comment: @hattenn you're joking, right? It's controller action, it cannot take any arguments.

Comment: lets see your routes, the problem im sure, is in there

Comment: @MarekLipka not joking "dude". He is somehow requesting the `chart` action without the `params` hash. So the `params` argument is not accessible to the `chart` action.

Comment: @hattenn no, it's not the case here, probably. `params` hash seems to be accessible (otherwise there would be `NoMethodError` raised), but `id` param is not passed. Why? I probably explained it already.

Comment: @L.D could you provide these information we asked?

Comment: instruments GET    /instruments(.:format)          instruments#index
 edit_instrument GET    /instruments/:id/edit(.:format) instruments#edit
      instrument GET    /instruments/:id(.:format)      instruments#show
                 PATCH  /instruments/:id(.:format)      instruments#update
                 PUT    /instruments/:id(.:format)      instruments#update
                 DELETE /instruments/:id(.:format)      instruments#destroy
           chart GET    /chart(.:format)                instruments#chart

Comment: chart dos not have format like show and I don't know how to change it in the routes.

Comment: Could you paste this in question? Also, it would be better if you gave `routes.rb` content, not the output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes, you have something like this:

```
resources :instruments do
  get 'chart', on: :collection
end
```

If you want to have `id` param in this route, you have to change it to member:

```
resources :instruments do
  get 'chart', on: :member
end
```

Don't forget you have to pass an id to the `chart` links, like this:

```
link_to 'chart', [:chart, instrument]
```

For more info about routing in Rails, you can check Guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help and for the link, I will study this for sure. The only change I had to make in order to have everything working properly was: link_to 'chart', [:chart, @instrument] . I had to use the local variable for instrument that one that is set by the method set_instrument. Also, I implemented the version using :member.